# Flex divs overlapping

Tags: html, css

I am new to flex and my problem is, when I resize the window, the divs overlap each other. I want them to shift to the next row automatically. Can anyone please tell me what I did wrong here? I am using `flex-wrap`, but, still, it's overlapping. Please refer to the below code.

```css
.flex-contain {
  display: flex;
  height: 30vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 50px;
}

.flex-contain>div {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-contain>div div {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px 80px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-contain">
  <div>
    <div>
      C++
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      HTML
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      CSS
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      Javascript
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      Java
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      Android
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      iOS
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      NodeJS
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably this `width: 25%;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `min-width` on your divs, otherwise, they will always be 25% the width of their parent:

```css
.flex-contain {
  display: flex;
  height: 30vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 50px;
}

.flex-contain>div {
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-contain>div div {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px 80px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-contain">
  <div>
    <div>
      C++
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      HTML
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      CSS
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      Javascript
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      Java
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      Android
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      iOS
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      NodeJS
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```